# AspectJ + Java 8 + Error while using ctrl click on variables

Tags: eclipse, aspectj, java-8, eclipse-luna

After Eclipse upgrade to Luna when I try using ctrl+click on variables in a class (calling Open Declaration) nothing happens.

Eclipse error log shows errors like this:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid length 65533 in LocalVariableTable in class file SomeClass
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.java.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:156)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.java.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.autowire.internal.provider.AutowireDependencyProvider.getBeansForType(AutowireDependencyProvider.java:360)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.autowire.internal.provider.AutowireDependencyProvider.getBeansForType(AutowireDependencyProvider.java:346)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.quickfix.hyperlinks.AutowireHyperlinkDetector$1.doWithActiveProjectClassLoader(AutowireHyperlinkDetector.java:139)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.java.JdtUtils$DefaultProjectClassLoaderSupport.executeCallback(JdtUtils.java:977)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.quickfix.hyperlinks.AutowireHyperlinkDetector.addHyperlinksHelper(AutowireHyperlinkDetector.java:136)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.quickfix.hyperlinks.AutowireHyperlinkDetector.addHyperlinksHelper(AutowireHyperlinkDetector.java:117)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.quickfix.hyperlinks.AutowireHyperlinkDetector.addHyperlinksHelper(AutowireHyperlinkDetector.java:94)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.quickfix.hyperlinks.AutowireHyperlinkDetector.addHyperlinks(AutowireHyperlinkDetector.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaElementHyperlinkDetector.detectHyperlinks(JavaElementHyperlinkDetector.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.HyperlinkDetectorRegistry$HyperlinkDetectorDelegate.detectHyperlinks(HyperlinkDetectorRegistry.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.mouseMove(HyperlinkManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

and

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.quickfix.hyperlinks.AutowireHyperlinkDetector.addHyperlinksHelper(AutowireHyperlinkDetector.java:148)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.quickfix.hyperlinks.AutowireHyperlinkDetector.addHyperlinksHelper(AutowireHyperlinkDetector.java:117)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.quickfix.hyperlinks.AutowireHyperlinkDetector.addHyperlinksHelper(AutowireHyperlinkDetector.java:94)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.quickfix.hyperlinks.AutowireHyperlinkDetector.addHyperlinks(AutowireHyperlinkDetector.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaElementHyperlinkDetector.detectHyperlinks(JavaElementHyperlinkDetector.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.HyperlinkDetectorRegistry$HyperlinkDetectorDelegate.detectHyperlinks(HyperlinkDetectorRegistry.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.mouseMove(HyperlinkManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Removing Spring Project nature from eclipse fixes the problem.
Removing AspectJ Capability form project also fixes the problem.
Removing all code containing lambda expressions also fixes the problem.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Looks like you have found a bug in the Aspectj Compiler. I recommend that you file a bug with the AspectJ project. It would be appreciated by the project maintainers.  http://bugs.eclipse.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using an old version of AspectJ since that problem was fixed in AspectJ 1.8.1 under https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435446 . The problem was due to weaving into code that contained invokedynamic instructions and try..catch blocks. Have you tried updating from the dev update site:

`http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/44/dev/update`